# Number of repeats in a regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Say I have the following regex:

```
"GGAGG.{5,13}?(ATG|GTG|TTG)(...)+?(TGA|TAA|TAG)"
```

Is there a way to see how many repeats are being done with for the part .{5,13}? 
Looking to know how far between GGAGG and a start codon. I could go and search for it manually later but wondering if there's a better way within the original regex.

Comment: Yes it has. If you provide a sample input, and expected output, then others can show you i believe.

Comment: You can simply put `.{5,13}?` in a capture group and obtain the length with the `len()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
"GGAGG(.{5,13}?)(ATG|GTG|TTG)(...)+?(TGA|TAA|TAG)"
```

and then use code like

```
rem = re.match(pat, s)
dist_between_ggagg_and_start_codon = len(rem.group(1))
```

Comment: be careful, here the question mark doesn't mean optional but make the preceding quantifier reluctant.

Comment: Believe I fixed that about the same time you were commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the entire match or groups using [`match.start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.start) method. Using that information:

```
>>> import re
>>> seq = 'xxxxGGAGGxxxxxxxATGxxxTGA'
>>> pattern = "GGAGG.{5,13}?(ATG|GTG|TTG)(...)+?(TGA|TAA|TAG)"
>>> match = re.search(pattern, seq)
>>> match.start(1) - match.start() - 5 # 5 = len(GGAGG)
7
```